# Apache Curator ZooKeeper Unit test Giving Error

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm trying to write unit tests for ZooKeeper using Apache Curator libraries. I'm using curator-test maven dependency. My code looks like this:

```
    final TestingCluster testingCluster = new TestingCluster(3);
    testingCluster.start();
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: configFileStr
at org.apache.curator.test.QuorumConfigBuilder$1.<init>(QuorumConfigBuilder.java:142)
at org.apache.curator.test.QuorumConfigBuilder.buildConfig(QuorumConfigBuilder.java:137)
at org.apache.curator.test.TestingZooKeeperServer$1.run(TestingZooKeeperServer.java:157)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried multiple combinations of curator versions to ZooKeeper versions. Currently, I'm using below maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-x-async</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/apache/curator/pull/248/commits/e37cb59c1e9b7ac7f21d3c3444b6bb789a3e3708

If you wish to use Curator's {{TestingServer}} with ZooKeeper 3.4.x you must use the older version of it.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're not excluding ZooKeeper from the recipes dependency. Also, you only show a partial pom. Have you read this doc? http://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility.html - see the section on "Testing With ZooKeeper 3.4.x".

Comment: I updated my maven dependency - excluded ZK from recipes. I'm now getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:138)
 at org.apache.curator.test.TestingZooKeeperServer$1.run(TestingZooKeeperServer.java:148)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
`

I updated the instances to 1, and it seems to work. Is there any restriction on no of ZK instances?